# menu id regex challenge

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I am currently working with the following pseudo code block to fix a regex problem I am running into.  currently I am using regex to find/remove various menu items based by id, however, it is only working for children, not the parent records.  so in this example I am trying to remove id53 and if you run the pseudo code you will see it breaks the structure of the tree b/c it does not remove the entire `<li></li>` block.

anyone have any ideas on how to adjust the regex test pattern we are working with?  I really appreciate your help and hope you have a great week.

```
<cfsavecontent variable="pseudo">
<ul id="nav-main-links">
    <li class="standby" id="id61"><a href="/?event=User.Home.dspHome" target="_self" title="Home"> Home<font class="menuItemType">(CB)</font></a>
    <li class="standby" id="id53"><a href="/contactus.cfm" target="_self" title="Contacts"> Contacts<font class="menuItemType">(L)</font></a>
    <ul class="sub-nav-main-links nestingLevel1">
        <li class="standby" id="id54"><a href="http://test/index.cfm" target="_self" title="Ven"> Ven<font class="menuItemType">(X)</font></a></li>
        <li class="standby" id="id55"><a href="http://test/spEvents.cfm" target="_self" title="SponsorShip"> SponsorShip<font class="menuItemType">(L)</font></a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</cfsavecontent>
<cfscript>
    myDisplay=structnew();
    myDisplay.pseudo=pseudo;
    myDisplay.IdsToRemove="53";
    myDisplay.RegExTestPattern='<li[^>]*?id="id(' & myDisplay.IdsToRemove & ')".*?li>';
    myDisplay.Menu=reReplaceNoCase(myDisplay.pseudo,myDisplay.RegExTestPattern,"","All");   
</cfscript>
<cfdump var="#myDisplay#">
```

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question, but regular expressions are the wrong tool for this job. You should use some sort of DOM library to do this.

Comment: I am sure this can be done a million different ways, hoping to fix it with regex though.

Comment: The problem is that a regular expression that is smart enough to detect an opening `<li>` child tag and then ignore the next closing `</li>` tag is going to be a very complicated.

Comment: yeah, I know, been working on it. I know it is possible though. the issue is it's finding the right starting point, just need to adjust the terminating spot

Comment: thanks man, I would switch it up, but there is already soo much wrapped around this I did not post

Comment: @Chris: a regex solution is *really* the wrong way to go unless you are forced into it somehow. ColdFusion can manipulate an XML document tree and you ought to make use of that.

Comment: I am considering switching out entirely but there is already so much hooked into this.  plus the menu system can have 1-x children with multiple sub children so I am trying to avoid recursion if at all possible.  still working this now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing a regex solution would need a recursive regex, and I don't know whether CFML supports that. As I commented, XML DOM manipulation is the way to go. It would look something like this (untested as I have no access to a ColdFusion server.

```xml
<cfsavecontent variable="pseudo">
<ul id="nav-main-links">
  <li class="standby" id="id61"><a href="/?event=User.Home.dspHome" target="_self" title="Home"> Home<font class="menuItemType">(CB)</font></a>
  <li class="standby" id="id53"><a href="/contactus.cfm" target="_self" title="Contacts"> Contacts<font class="menuItemType">(L)</font></a>
  <ul class="sub-nav-main-links nestingLevel1">
    <li class="standby" id="id54"><a href="http://test/index.cfm" target="_self" title="Ven"> Ven<font class="menuItemType">(X)</font></a></li>
    <li class="standby" id="id55"><a href="http://test/spEvents.cfm" target="_self" title="SponsorShip"> SponsorShip<font class="menuItemType">(L)</font></a></li>
  </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
</cfsavecontent>

<cfscript>

  myDisplay=structnew();
  myDisplay.IdsToRemove = "53";
  idVal = 'id' & myDisplay.IdsToRemove;

  xmlTree = xmlParse(pseudo);
  liList = xmlSearch(xmlTree, '//li[@id="' & idVal & '"]');
  arrayDeleteAt(liList, 0);

  myDisplay.pseudo = toString(xmlTree);

</cfscript>

<cfdump var="#myDisplay#">
```

Comment: I am giving this a few tests now, will let you know, thank you so much for your help

Comment: ok, I really like where this is going, however, the string in question is minified so I have to figure out a way to get xmlparse to work on it.

Comment: the single string conversion is turning out to be a pain too :(

Comment: @chris hough: if it is minified properly it should stay as valid XML. However I notice that you have four `<li>` opening tags and only three `</li>` closing tags. If your data is really like this then you will have a problem manipulating it using any method. Not sure what you mean by *single string conversion*.

Comment: I am reworking my entire process now into XML, you are correct, I was setting this up wrong. thank you for your guidance, I really appreciate it.